# Accounts payables, accounts receivables, invoices, and bills

Tags: finance, prices

I'm looking for a big sample of accounts (payable or receivable) or bills. No matter if it's structured data, scans, or physical receipts.

I haven't found data more relevant than government contracts. But contracts usually include a bulk of goods and services, and it's difficult to separate those.

Some firms use software to manage their accounts, but that's closed data, even when exportable.

Do you have any hints where I can get it anyway?

Answer (score 2):

How about a government jurisdiction's ledger? This would be more granular than for each contract and instead be for each check written.

Some examples:

- State of Iowa: Ledger data at https://data.iowa.gov/d/9sag-ywd8; Exploratory UI at http://checkbook.iowa.gov/
- City of Danvilla, VA: Ledger data at https://data.danvilleva.gov/d/2b9c-d6ip; Exploratory UI at http://budget.danvilleva.gov/
- City of Oxnard, CA: Accounts Payable transactions data https://data.oxnard.org/d/ay6a-gmt6
- City of South Bend, IN: Check Register Accounts Payable data: https://data.southbendin.gov/d/5pfq-kbdb

You can find many more by searching the Open Data Network`*` at http://www.opendatanetwork.com/search?q=accounts%20payable

`*` *Disclaimer*: I work for the company that created the Open Data Network

Comment: I also found for Vermont (2.5M records): https://data.burlingtonvt.gov/State-of-Vermont/State-of-Vermont-Accounts-Payable-Payments-2008-20/ruic-gixv . Thanks, btw.